# Redirect stdin and stdout in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to create a bash script where it executes java command like:

```
java App < stdin > stdout 2> stderr
```

so I can run this script, pass files to stdin, stdout, stderr and it would execute it.

```
./script < file1 > file2 2> file3
```

And it's gonna do:

```
java App < file1 > file2 2> file3
```

How to redirect input and output?

Comment: Doc here: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java` already inherits its file descriptors from the shell, so you don't have to do *anything* special inside the script:

```
java App
```